# Laravel 7 (php 7.4) showing data from database in tiny editor,

Tags: php, laravel, email, tinymce

i have admin page to edit email template. for mail body i use tiny editor.

for example, my email template in tiny editor like this

```
Hi {{$name}} Your Administrator account has been deactivated. Please contact xxxxx
```

but in email that i received, the result that i get also **{{$name}}**, not real User name that i declare in controller

my controller

```
 $name=$user->name;
 $template = Template::where('code',1)->first();
 Mail::send('mail.user', compact('template','name'), function ($message) use (xxx) {
        $message->from(xxx);
        $message->subject('test');
        $message->to($email, $fullname);
    });
 }
```

my blade

```
{!! $template ->text_email!!}
```

so this text `Hi {{$name}} Your Administrator account has been deactivated. Please contact xxxxx` actually will show in blade above.

i try to show {{$name}} by use code below, but the result in email still the same as per i wrote in tiny,not show the real username

```
@php 
   echo $name;
@endphp


{{ !! $name !! }}


{{ !! htmlspecialchars_decode($name) !! }} 

 {{ !! html_entity_decode($name) !! }}
```

Comment: Let me ask first, because I use Laravel for last time ago. Can you tell which version do you use of Laravel?

Comment: hi, im using laravel 7, php 7.4

Comment: Have you try to change from `{{$name}}` to `{!! $name !!}`?